# Сложный калькулятор с++, считающий выражения

Tags: c++, польская-запись

Как создать на с++ калькулятор, способный считать целые выражения. К примеру, пользователь может сразу ввести 4-3*2, а не считать это по действиям.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рекомендовал бы недавно вышедшую книгу Страуструп. *Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++* (только второе издание, первое - это ошибка на ошибке). Там именно этот вопрос детально разбирается на протяжении пары глав.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно нагуглить такие вещи как:

- [обратная польская запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)
- [AST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)
- [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
- [стековая машина](https://habrahabr.ru/post/223887/)